# How to implement a strategy pattern with runtime selection of a method?

Tags: python, inheritance, strategy-pattern

***Context***

I'm trying to implement some variant of strategy pattern in Python 2.7.
I want to be able to instantiate a 'my_strategy' base class, but switch between different implementations of a 'score' method at run-time.
I will have many common methods in 'my_strategy' but a bunch of 'score' implementations.
The **main** illustrates how I want to use it.
Here the scoring implementation is dummy of course.

***What I tried (i.e. My code so far)***

strategy.py:

```
from algo_one import *
#from algo_two import *


class my_strategy ( object ):

    def __init__(self, candidate = ""):
        self.candidate = candidate
        self.method = 'default'
        self.no = 10
        self._algo = algo_one

    def set_strategy(self, strategy='default'):
        self.strategy = strategy
        if self.strategy == 'algo_one':
            self._algo = algo_one
        elif self.strategy == 'algo_two':
            # self._algo = algo_two
            pass 
        else:
            self._algo = None

    def score(self, *args):
        if len(args) > 0:
            self.candidate = args[0]
        self._algo.score(self.candidate)

if  __name__ == "__main__":
    s = my_strategy()  
    s.strategy = 'algo_one'
    s.candidate = "hello world"
    print s.score()  
    print s.score("hi")
    # s.set_method('algo_two')
    # print s.score("hi")
```

I want to save the selected strategy in some sort of private pointer to the sub-class method.

algo_one.py:

```
from strategy import my_strategy
class algo_one ( my_strategy ):    
    def score(self, candidate):
        return len(candidate)*self.no
```

I could have a class-less method, but later I'll need to access public variables of the base class.

algo_two.py:

```
from strategy import my_strategy
class algo_two ( my_strategy ):
    def score(self, candidate):
        return len(candidate)*3
```

I have an empty **init**.py too.

***The errors***

**1.**
in score self._algo.score(self.candidate)

> TypeError: unbound method score() must be called with algo_one
>   instance as first argument (got str instance instead)

**2.**
If I uncomment the import of the second strategy:

```
from algo_two import *
```

I get the following error.

> ImportError: cannot import name my_strategy

My guess is that I run into some sort of circular dependency.

**3.**

```
from algo_one import *
```

This is obviously not pretty (unable to detect undefined names), but if I

```
from algo_one import algo_one
```

I get

> ImportError: cannot import name algo_one

***Question***

I think the errors are intertwined and that my approach, as a whole, may be flawed. If not just addressing the error, I'm looking for suggestions to improve the design. Or any comment, really. Also I'm open to suggestions regarding the title of this question. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You make it much more complicated than it needs to be. Python functions are first class objects so the simplest way to implement the strategy pattern in Python is to pass a 'strategy' function to your "context" object (the one that uses the strategy). The fine part is that any callable object (ie: any object implementing the `__call__` method) will work.

```
def default_score_strategy(scorer):
    return len(scorer.candidate) * 3

def universal_answer_score_strategy(scorer):
    return 42 # definitly the universal answer <g>

class ComplicatedStrategy(object):
    def __init__(self, factor):
        self.factor = factor

    def __call__(self, scorer):
         return len(scorer.candidate) * self.factor


class Scorer(object):
    def __init__(self, candidate="", strategy=default_score_strategy):
        self.candidate = candidate
        self.strategy = strategy

    def score(self):
        return self.strategy(self)

s1 = Scorer("foo")
s2 = Scorer("bar", strategy=universal_answer_score_strategy)
s3 = Scorer("baaz", strategy=ComplicatedStrategy(365))
```

Note that your strategies dont have to be in the same module as the `Scorer` class (well, except the default one of course), and that the module containing the `Scorer` class doesn't have to import the stratgeies modules - nor know anything about where the strategies are defined:

```
# main.py

from mylib.scores import Scorer
from myapp.strategies import my_custom_strategy

s = Scorer("yadda", my_custom_strategy)
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you.
Of course the `ComplicatedStrategy` class will not see any method or variable of the `Scorer` class. So I got the former to inherit from the later (`class ComplicatedStrategy( Scorer ):`) and this answers my needs perfectly.

Comment: @Hugues please reread : the `ComplicatedStrategy` instance DO have access to the `Scorer` instance which is passed to the `__call__` method. You _dont_ need inheritance here, definitly (and it wouldn't solve anything anyway - you'd still need to pass the `Scorer` instance to access it's own attributes).

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't instantiate your algo object in the `__init__` method. Remember, to instantiate a class object, you need to call it:

   ```
   self._algo = algo_one()
   ```
2. Yes, that's a circular dependency. I don't see however why algo_one and algo_two need to inherit from my_strategy at all. Just make them plain objects, or inherit a base class stored somewhere else. Or, keep them all in the same file - there's no reason to necessarily have classes in separate files in Python.
3. This is the same problem as 2.

Comment: Thank you.
1. That creates this error instead: `NameError: global name 'algo_one' is not defined`
2. a) Because I want algo_one to use some common methods and variables in my_strategy. 
   b) ok thanks I could use a base class
   c) well you cannot know that, but the length of this file will soon get out of control (not with my simple example obviously).

Answer (score 1):

One of your main problems are that your algorithms try to subclass from your base class, which is a huge design flaw (you already noticed that). Use a simple method binding instead, which deals with all the necessary things:

```
def algo_one(candidate):
    # do stuff
    return "A fluffy unicorn"

def algo_two(candidate):
    # do some other stuff
    return "Awesome rabbits"

# not really necessary, just to make it easier to add new algorithms
STRATEGIES = { "one": algo_one, "two": algo_two }

class Strategy(object):
     def __init__(self):
         ...

     def set_strategy(self, which):
         if which not in STRATEGIES:
             raise ValueError("'%s' is an unknown strategy" % which)
         # compatibility checks  about the entries in STRATEGIES omitted here
         self._algo = STRATEGIES[which]

     def score(self, *args):
         # ...
         return self._algo(...)
```

If you need a more complex approach (this however depends on your requirements), in which everyone knows about each other, split the algorithms and strategy chooser into different classes referencing each other (shortened version below):

```
class ScoreAlgo(object):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self._strategy = parent # if you need a back-reference, just be aware of circular dependencies in the garbage collection
    def __del__(self):
        self._strategy = None # resolve circular dependency for the GC

    def score(self, candidate):
        return None

class Strategy(object):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
    def set_strategy(self, ...):
        ...
        self._algo = ScoreAlgo(self)

    def score(self, ...):
        return self._algo.score(...)
```

(If you need a huge variety of algorithms, you should make ScoreAlgo an abstract base class, for which subclasses have to implement the score() method).

You also could use a mixin pattern (which is a bit more formal than the method binding) or several other ways. This however depends on your overall requirements.

**EDIT:** I just added a `return`to both `def score():` stubs to avoid confusion about why those might not return anything.

Comment: Not clear to me what I have to replace the ... with in
`def score(self, *args):
        self._algo(...)`
I do `s = Strategy(), s.set_strategy("one"), s.score()
` and it returns None.

Comment: For method2, I edited the ScoreAlgo.score with return 42. Same issue it doesn't return anything.

Comment: Of course, you have to implement the stubs properly to comply with your requirements. So, `def score(self): ...` in the `Strategy` class would need to return the value of `self._algo.score(...)`

The same applies to the first example.